# Simplify multinomial trig expansion to fewer linear terms like Wolfram?

Tags: trigonometry, wolfram-alpha

I'm mystified as to how Wolfram Alpha's [TrigReduce[expr]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TrigReduce.html) does its magic, particularly on *sums of long products* that look like
$$A \cos^a(B_1 x) \sin^b(B_2 x) \cos^c (B_3 x) \sin^d (B_4 x) \dots$$

I can get to a linear combination of sines & cosines by using power-reduction and product-to-sum formulas, but this yields wayyy more terms than the original expansion, while Wolfram's method yields way *fewer*. E.g. $\approx 2500$ vs $59$ (!?). What is the trick?

Here's what I'm able to do on my own, taking one term of a multinomial expansion:

$$\begin{align}
& A \cos^2 (B x) \sin(C x) \sin^2 (D x) \cos(E x) \\
= & \frac{A}{4}\big[1 + \cos(2 B x)\big] \sin(C x) \big[1 - \cos(2 D x)\big] \cos(E x) \\
= & \frac{A}{4} \big[ -\cos(2 B x) \sin(C x) \cos(2 D x) \cos (E x) - \sin(C x) \cos(2 D x) \cos(E x) + \cos(2 B x) \sin(C x) \cos(E x) + \sin(C x) \cos(E x) \big]
\end{align}$$

Then I can perform splits like the following:
$$\begin{align}
& \cos(2 B x) \sin(C x) \cos(E x) \\
& = \frac{1}{2}\big[\sin((2B+C)x) - \sin((2B-C)x)\big] \cos(E x) \\
& = \frac{1}{2}\sin((2B+C)x)\cos(Ex) - \frac{1}{2}\sin((2B-C)x)\cos(Ex) \\
& = \frac{1}{4}\big[\sin((2B+C+E)x) + \sin((2B+C-E)x) - \sin((2B-C+E)x) - \sin((2B-C-E)x)\big]
\end{align}$$

This small example fails to demonstrate how the # of terms blows up when recursively applying product-to-sum formulas, suggesting there's more to the story of $\text{TrigReduce}$.

Informally, I'll let $s_n$ denote a sum of $n$ trig functions and $p_n$ denote a product of $n$ trig functions. So the splitting example shown above would be expressed as:
$$p_3 = (s_2)p_1 = p_2 + p_2 = s_2 + s_2 = s_4$$

Splitting a term of $6$ trig factors would then be expressed as:
$$\begin{align}
p_6 & = (s_2)p_4 = p_5 + p_5 = (s_2)p_3 + (s_2)p_3 = p_4 + p_4 + p_4 + p_4 \\
& = (s_2)p_2 + (s_2)p_2 + (s_2)p_2 + (s_2)p_2 = p_3 \times 8 = s_4 \times 8
\end{align}$$

In general, it appears that splitting a product of $n$ trig factors using product-to-sum formulas yields $2^{n-1}$ linear terms.

Suppose I want to simplify the following expression:
$$(\cos(3x) + \sin(5x) + \cos(7x) + \sin(11x))^6$$

The number of terms in the multinomial expansion is $\binom{6+4-1}{4-1} = 84$. Each term is a product of $6$ trig functions (since the exponents in each term must sum to $6$ according to multinomial theorem). As per the earlier formula, a product of $6$ trig functions splits into $32$ linear terms. Not counting the effect of power reduction (PR) formulae, $84 \cdot 32 = 2688$ linear terms. If my intuition is correct, the effect of PR is no better than product-to-sum conversions, because for each exponent that is cut in half, the entire enclosing term gets duplicated (since there are two terms in a PR formula). So roughly $\approx 2688$ terms is the best I know how to do.

However, TrigReduce [applied](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=trigreduce%28%28cos%283*x%29+%2B+sin%285*x%29+%2B+cos%287*x%29+%2B+sin%2811*x%29%29%5E6%29) to same expression spits out a mere **59** linear sin/cos terms (!?!). How is this possible? Is Wolfram doing something tricky across the *sums* of the product strings?

Would appreciate any clues. I know I've posted a few lame tumbleweeds lately; maybe my allowance of dumb questions is reaching a limit. I wouldn't ask this except it's the missing puzzle-piece in an algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for Wolfram's astonishingly low term count for the OP example, is that the example given is a special case.

Because the initial sin/cos arguments are small integers, the set of unique argument sums as computed in the product-to-sum conversions is a *very small set*--- just **59** unique arguments, to be exact. So for the OP example, the answer is "combine like terms." There is no magic.

More significant digits in the initial sin/cos arguments means more combinations of possible argument sums, causing Wolfram's $\text{TrigReduce}$ to output an exploding # of terms. I didn't count exactly, but the number easily approaches the order of the OP estimate, i.e. $\approx\binom{n+t-1}{t-1} 2^{n-1}$.